# (LIBGDX) args instead of variables names

Tags: java, libgdx

I added Kryonet to my libgdx project like this...

Created a "libs" folder in core project, droped kryonet.jar in there.
In build.gradle of the root project added this line:

```
project(":core") {
   ...
   dependencies {
    ...
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   }
}
```

### But I keep seeing "arg" instead of the variable names

[image]

## When I try to see the class this is what it shows:

[image]

No button to attach source is being displayed..
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I believe the problem is that you're only including the binaries, so your IDE can't figure out what the original variable names were. If you include the source code as well, that lets your IDE be a little smarter.

I would propose an alternative implementation- instead of putting those JAR files in a libs directory, add them to your gradle file as maven imports instead as follows:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        // ... your other compile lines here
        // Add the kryonet line below:
        compile "com.esotericsoftware:kryonet:2.22.0-RC1"
    }
}
```

This appears to add everything the IDE needs to both import the code and label the parameters.

Comment: This worked, I have a question, where in `https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet` you found that string? `com.esotericsoftware:kryonet:2.22.0-RC1` cuz I was looking for this and couldnt find it so I did the libs folder method

Comment: I actually didn't- I went to `https://search.maven.org` and searched for kryonet. The first entry seemed to be the library I wanted, and from there the gradle syntax is `compile "<groupid>:<artifactid>:<version>"`